# Assign jQuery on 'click' function to ajax generated lists elements before they are in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, for-loop

I am building an `ajax` generated menu using `JSON`, creating the `<li>` elements in a `for loop` and adding each list item to a variable before placing all the list items on the page.

The `for loop` is iterating over a dataset that holds the next URL I will be ajaxing from based on the `li` element that get's clicked.

I am guessing I will end up having to run another `for loop` to assign the click event once the list is added to the page if setting it before hand is not possible

I additionally, even though it works, do not want to build my `getJSON` method into the html `onclick` attribute as this would expose the JSON nav URL in the DOM.

This is a working example of what I do not what to do when building out my markup.

Is it possible to assign a click event in the for loop to the most recently created `<li>` in my variable before I place it on the page?

```
newLinks += (dataSet[i].has_child > 0) ? '<span class="child arrow" onclick="getJSON(' + dataSet[i].nav_url + ',' + childCheck + ')"></span>' : '';
```

Below is my markup builder function

```
function buildLists() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    newLinks += '<li ';
    newLinks += 'class="';
    newLinks += (dataSet[i].selected === true ) ? 'selected ' : '';
    newLinks += dataSet[i].display_status + '';
    newLinks += (dataSet[i].has_child > 0) ? ' hasChild' : '';
    newLinks += '"'; // end class attribute
    newLinks += '>';
    newLinks += (dataSet[i].has_child > 0) ? '<span class="child arrow"></span>' : '';
    newLinks += '<a href="' + dataSet[i].url + '"';
    newLinks += 'id="' + dataSet[i].id + '"';
    newLinks += '>';
    newLinks += dataSet[i].name;
    newLinks += '</a>';
    newLinks += '</li>';
    childCheck = (dataSet[i].node_type !== 'childInstance');
    $j(newLinks).on('click', function() {
      getJSON( dataSet[i].nav_url, childCheck );
    })
  }
  newLinks = '<ul>' + newLinks + '</ul>';
  placeContent();
}
```

The `placeContent();` function then adds the `newLinks` variable to the page. This is where I assume I may have to loop over the `dataSet` and assign the `on click` function once the list items are in the DOM.

**EDIT:** I used a combination of both answers provided here is my updated code which functions as needed:

I am now assigning a click event to the wrapper and passing in an additional class to my `span` element. This allows me to create unique click events while still being in the for loop and assigning them to the relent element in the DOM

```
function buildLists() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    newLinks += '<li ';
    newLinks += 'class="';
    newLinks += (dataSet[i].selected === true ) ? 'selected ' : '';
    newLinks += dataSet[i].display_status + '';
    newLinks += (dataSet[i].has_child > 0) ? ' hasChild' : '';
    newLinks += '"'; // end class attribute
    newLinks += '>';
    newLinks += (dataSet[i].has_child > 0) ? '<span class="child arrow ' + dataSet[i].id + '"></span>' : '';
    newLinks += '<a href="' + dataSet[i].url + '"';
    newLinks += 'id="' + dataSet[i].id + '"';
    newLinks += '>';
    newLinks += dataSet[i].name;
    newLinks += '</a>';
    newLinks += '</li>';
    $j('.menu').on('click', '.' + dataSet[i].id , createItem(dataSet[i].nav_url));
  }
  newLinks = '<ul>' + newLinks + '</ul>';
  placeContent();
}
```

Then I run the `createItem` function. Additionally I am unbinding click from the `.menu` selector so the `getJSON` function and corresponding `for loop` do not keep firing multiple clicks.

```
function createItem(url) {
  return function() {
    $j('.menu').unbind('click');
    getJSON( url, true );
  };
}
```

Comment: Are your `li` elements being added to the HTML after form load? I mean, dynamically?

Comment: Yes, the `li` elements are being added dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about Closure. 
You just need to have a function out of `BuildLists` like

```
function createItem(url) {
  return function() {
    getJSON( url, childCheck );
  };
}
```

then change your code to

```
$j(newLinks).on('click', createItem(dataSet[i].nav_url));
```

Comment: Marked this one correct as it was mostly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Use the on click event this way to add on your new content:

```
$(document).on("click", ajaxGeneratedSelector, function(){
  // Your code
}
```

Comment: This could work but I am currently using generic classes in my list and span elements I am building

Comment: Decided to go with a combination, I am assigning the click to the ajaxGeneratedSelector in combination with the answer provided